# переопределение статических методов при наследовании классов с использованием @Override

Tags: java, методы, static

Animals

```
public class Animals {

    public static void run(){
        System.out.println("Животное бежит");
    }
}
```

Cat

```
public class Cat extends Animals {

    public static void run(){
        System.out.println("Животное бежит");
    }
}
```

Main

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cat.run();
    }
}
```

По такой структуре мы можем переопределять статический метод и, запустив, увидим в консоли "`Животное бежит`", но если мы сделаем вот так:

```
public class Cat extends Animals {
    @Override
    public static void run(){
        System.out.println("Животное бежит");
    }
}
```

То будет выдавать ошибку и писать:

```
Method does not override method from its superclass
```

Получается, я могу переопределять статические методы, но только не нужно помечать сверху метод аннотацией `@Override`?

Comment: вопрос хороший, но заголовок...

Comment: @Bogdan исправьте, я приму правки

Comment: нашел хороший топик на [англоязычном StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2223405/5441023) на эту тему.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае происходит обычная перегрузка. Статические методы не переопределяются, они существуют на уровне классов. По этому утрачиваются полиморфные свойства. Например:

```
Animal animal = new Cat();
animal.f();
```

В данном случае `animal.run()` воспринимается как `Animal.run()`.